# Can an executable be scanned for calls to the vulnerable glibc ghost functions?

Tags: ghost, glibc, scan

The ghost vulnerability has the potential to be vulnerable to many many pieces of software that call the gethostbyname() and gethostbyname2() functions.  Is there an easy way to scan an executable to determine if it makes use of either of these two vulnerable functions?  While this wouldn't tell you if a program was vulnerable, it can tell you if it's NOT vulnerable.

To use either of these functions, I believe the executable (or 3rd party library) must link to it.  It seems to me you should be able to scan the executable for a link to the shared library.

Answer (score 1):

To find out if this calls are used, you could simply do a

```
strings -a /bin/ip | grep gethost
```

Another approach returning more information is

```
readelf --dyn-syms /bin/ip | grep gethost
```

Comment: Be sure to check all of the libraries that the executable links against, too!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are few ways to get the info, `nm` and `objdump` are your friends.

---

**Demo**

For demo purposes, I've used a [PoC](https://itservices.uchicago.edu/page/ghost-vulnerability) developed by the University of Chicago to test if a system is vulnerable or not to the `Ghost` vulnerability.

Here's the code:

```
/*
 * GHOST vulnerability check
 * http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2015/01/27/9
 * Usage: gcc GHOST.c -o GHOST && ./GHOST
 */ 

#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define CANARY "in_the_coal_mine"

struct {
  char buffer[1024];
  char canary[sizeof(CANARY)];
} temp = { "buffer", CANARY };

int main(void) {
  struct hostent resbuf;
  struct hostent *result;
  int herrno;
  int retval;

  /*** strlen (name) = size_needed - sizeof (*host_addr) - sizeof (*h_addr_ptrs) - 1; ***/
  size_t len = sizeof(temp.buffer) - 16*sizeof(unsigned char) - 2*sizeof(char *) - 1;
  char name[sizeof(temp.buffer)];
  memset(name, '0', len);
  name[len] = '\0';

  retval = gethostbyname_r(name, &resbuf, temp.buffer, sizeof(temp.buffer), &result, &herrno);

  if (strcmp(temp.canary, CANARY) != 0) {
    puts("vulnerable");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
  if (retval == ERANGE) {
    puts("not vulnerable");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
  puts("should not happen");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Then compile the code to generate the binary:

```
$ gcc GHOST.c -o ghost
```

Test if an *unstripped* binary contains `gethostbyname*` symbols:
`$ nm ghost | grep gethost
    U gethostbyname_r@@GLIBC_2.2.5`
... and sure it does.

Now, it's also possible the binary has been stripped of debugging symbols:

`# stripping away debug symbols
$ strip -o ghost-stripped ghost
$ nm ghost-stripped 
nm: ghost-stripped: no symbols`

In that case, you can use `objdump`:
`$ objdump -T ghost-stripped 
ghost-stripped:     file format elf64-x86-64
DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
...
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 gethostbyname_r
...`

... filter to only what we're looking for:
`$ objdump -T ghost-stripped | grep gethostbyname
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  GLIBC_2.2.5 gethostbyname_r`